# NVIDIA Linux-x86_64-387.34 driver version is not working for Ubuntu 16.04.3 64 bit with NVIDIA Graphic card "GeForce GT 730"

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, cuda

I have HP Elite 800 G2 desktop with Ubuntu 16.04.3 64 bit with NVIDIA Graphic card "GeForce GT 730".

```
$ lshw -numeric -C display
*-display UNCLAIMED description: VGA 
compatible controller product: GK208 [GeForce GT 730] [10DE:1287] 
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE] 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
version: a1 
width: 64 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pci express vga_controller bus_master cap_list configuration: latency=0 
resources: 
memory:db000000-dbffffff 
memory:d0000000-d7ffffff 
memory:d8000000-d9ffffff 
ioport:3000(size=128) 
memory:dc080000-dc0fffff 
*-display description: VGA 
compatible controller product: Sky Lake 
Integrated Graphics [8086:1912] vendor: Intel Corporation [8086] 
physical id: 2 
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 
version: 06 
width: 64 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pci express msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 
resources: irq:129 
memory:da000000-daffffff 
memory:c0000000-cfffffff 
ioport:4000(size=64)
```

---

```
$ apt-get install cuda
Install: cuda-libraries-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-gpu-library-advisor-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-command-line-tools-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-visual-tools-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-driver-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-runtime-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-curand-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
libcuda1-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2, automatic), 
nvidia-modprobe:amd64 (387.26-0ubuntu1, automatic), 
cuda-drivers:amd64 (387.26-1, automatic), 
cuda-cuobjdump-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvgraph-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvgraph-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cudart-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-license-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-demo-suite-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cusparse-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-samples-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-curand-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-npp-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cufft-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvdisasm-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
nvidia-387-dev:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2, automatic), 
cuda-cusparse-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 (9.0.0-2.1, automatic), 
cuda-cusolver-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-npp-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvvp-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-tools-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cupti-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvtx-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cublas-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cublas-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cusolver-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cudart-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-gdb-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvprune-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-cufft-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvml-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-toolkit-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvrtc-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-misc-headers-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-compiler-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvrtc-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nsight-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
freeglut3-dev:amd64 (2.8.1-2, automatic), 
cuda:amd64 (9.1.85-1), 
cuda-documentation-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-memcheck-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
nvidia-opencl-icd-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2, automatic), 
cuda-nvcc-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
nvidia-387:amd64 (387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2, automatic), 
cuda-libraries-dev-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
cuda-nvprof-9-1:amd64 (9.1.85-1, automatic), 
nvidia-settings:amd64 (390.12-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1, automatic)
```

After getting latest updates from Ubuntu sites.
The system is running in low-graphics mode after reboot.
I have tried all previous community answers using apt-get or direct NVIDIA driver for all version installation but nothing works.

The error in Xorg.0.log is given below:

```
[    49.889] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    49.889] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    49.890] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    49.890]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    49.890]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.890] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    49.890] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    49.890] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.890]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.14
.
.
.
    36.321] (EE) Backtrace:
[    36.324] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x5604ca488e1e]
[    36.324] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5604ca2d7000+0x1b5b89) [0x5604ca48cb89]
[    36.324] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fcaed644000+0x11390) [0x7fcaed655390]
[    36.324] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (RRProviderAutoConfigGpuScreen+0x42) [0x5604ca3f6132]
[    36.324] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0x5bd) [0x5604ca36fb2d]
[    36.324] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x5604ca2d7000+0x581a6) [0x5604ca32f1a6]
[    36.324] (EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7fcaed29a830]
[    36.324] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x29) [0x5604ca319329]
[    36.324] (EE)
[    36.324] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x130
[    36.324] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    36.324] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

Can anyone help me to configure NVIDIA Graphics card for Ubuntu display settings?

Comment: Do you have UEFI with Secure Boot enabled? Try disabling it as it prevents loading unsigned drivers.

Comment: Use the formatting tools - your post is unreadable.

Comment: Secure boot manipulations didn't save me. 387 just doesn't seem to work for me. 384 though, is fine. Haven't tried 390 yet.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed **Ubuntu 16.04.3 64 Bit**. And configured my **Nvidia GPU** by following [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux) guide. Before you perform installation, remove all the nvidia components by using this command: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

**Note:** It is recommended to have latest version of kernel installed for drivers to work properly. [Here](https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/) is the guide to upgrade kernel for Ubuntu. 
On this site they have mention the link to see latest available kernels. You can try the latest one. Mine is `4.14.0`. On this, the drivers works fine.

After installation, you can manage your GPU setting from **NVIDIA X Server Settings**. Type `sudo nvidia-settings` in terminal to access it.

If, in case above solution doesn't work, try downloading drivers form [Here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html)   . The version you mentioned in the heading is available. But see to that before installing this driver, you remove the previously available components using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Hope this answer will solve your problem.